# Different tooltips problem

Tags: tables, design, style

So I am having kind of a issue, the client NEEDS to have 2 tooltips, as shown in the image below:

[image: Tooltips]

But one is on the title of the section and the other one is inside the table. My question is if I should have 2 different styles of tooltips (inside the table only border and the "i" blue, for example) or should I keep them both the same?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, we are not talking about the tooltip, but about the tooltip indicator

[image: tootltip]

I think at least in this case, functionality prevails over aesthetics, where, beyond the meaning, the main function is for the user to identify the same shape, color, and size immediately to locate where the elements with help text are:

[image: tootltips]

<sub>*Image source [mediawiki.org](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:SimpleTooltip)*</sub>

In the example of the question, instead of worrying about color, figure/ground, or formal differences, I would do an in-depth analysis of the design consistency.

[image: Design consistency]

Comment: Perfect. Just to clarify the image is of their website, I am working on the new version. And the piece on the right (you marked as ?) is just another column on the table.
I will try to maintain the consistency as I see it's more important. Thank you very much :D

Answer (score 0):

Tooltip indicators are for suggesting that there is an additional info to that text component. It would be better to retain the consistent style everywhere so that user develops visual imagery around such available info and may not end up spending extra time to spot and visually distinguish them.

Here is the link to great some insight around tooltips: https://www.nngroup.com/articles/tooltip-guidelines/